# Is there a way to make an array of "sub-enumeration" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Consider:

```
type
  TEnum = (e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10);

const
  ENUM_ARR: array[TEnum] of integer = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

procedure Proc;
var
  subEnumArr: array[e3..e5] of integer;
  enumVar: TEnum;
begin
  for enumVar := Low(subEnumArr) to High(subEnumArr) do
    subEnumArr[enumVar] := ENUM_ARR[enumVar];
end;
```

This works perfectly fine. But lets say I want to construct an array with some more complicated set of enumeration, something like:

```
subEnumArr: array[e1, e3..e5, e7, e9..e10] of integer;
```

So delphi wouldn't allow that and I wonder if there is an elegant solution to this.

Comment: Do you really need the extra subarrays? Would it not be sufficient to declare `TMyEnumSet = set of TEnum; const mySet : TMySet = [e1, e3..e5, e7, e9..e10]; var e : TEnum;` and then use: `for e in mySet do WriteLn(ENUM_ARR[e]);`

Comment: Arrays require indices that have contiguous ordinal value.

Comment: Honestly, in that specific use case, I would simply use array[TEnum] and ignore the unused values.

Comment: If not for being stuck on XE, this is effectively a great use case for a TDictionary.  In fact, a number of generic constructs would lend themselves to various implementations of what it sounds like you're after.  Beyond that, I don't think there's a clean way to do this (assuming you need the stack allocation of a fixed array and assuming you cannot allocate the full array for whatever reason) without maintainting a couple of arrays to hold the list of indices you care about and an index cross-reference.

Comment: @J... Invariably when you see a question tagged XE this is a mistake and the user is on a more modern version. Quite often a version 10.x!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Dare we answer it on that assumption? I'd say that's nearly a new leaf turning over...

Comment: @J... I don't think a dictionary is much use here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Except that OP seems to want to store key/value pairs.

Comment: @J... I'm not seeing it quite like that. Arrays are ordered for a start.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And OP is fighting that order trying to index and allocate using a disjoint subset of the full key set. It could be an XY blunder to begin with, but if we assume this is the implementation OP wants, I think it's not an unreasonable option.

Comment: @J... I'd just stick them in an array personally. But I'm not sure I really know what is desired here. If ever you need an ordered dictionary, you know there is one in spring4d?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OP seems to care about enumerable, not necessarily ordered. They can provide more information, tbh, the broader intent here is certainly not clear.